# How to get rid of the rhombus-like shapes from the altair steamgraph?

Tags: python, jupyter, altair

I have an altair graph which mostly works well, but based on the data can end up being distorted. One example is:

[image]

How to explain that, and how to fix it?
Here is the source code

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

_properties_to_display = ['moving_average_count','moving_average_value']
brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])

selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['Command'])
color = alt.condition(
    selection,
    alt.Color('Command:N').legend(None).scale(scheme='category20b'),
    alt.value('lightgray')
)

base = alt.Chart(dfx.reset_index().dropna(subset=_properties_to_display), width=1600, height=600)

def steamgraph(value_name):
    return base.mark_area().encode(
            x = alt.X("minute:T")
                .title("Time")
                .axis(
                    labelAngle=0,
                    labelOverlap=False
                ),
            y = alt.Y(f"{value_name}:Q", type='quantitative').impute(value=0).stack('center').axis(None),
            color = color,
            tooltip=dataset_labels_for_tooltip
        ).add_params(
            selection
        ).transform_timeunit(
            minute='hoursminutes(Bucket)'
        ).properties(
            title=f"Steamgraph {value_name}"
        )

alt.vconcat(steamgraph("moving_average_count"), steamgraph('moving_average_value'))
```